# How do I limit the number of characters shown in an XML record in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asprepeater

I have an XML source and one of the fields is "description" which can vary in length but is always rather long. When I'm passing this to my asp.net repeater, I'd like to limit the number of characters that are displayed for consistency and brevity's sake. Is there any way to do this? Say... 300 characters.

Thank you in advance!

My front end code:

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="xPathRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <h3><%#XPath ("title") %></h3>
                <p><%#XPath("description")%></p>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

My code behind:

```
    protected void XMLsource()
{
    string URLString = "http://ExternalSite.com/xmlfeed.asp";

    XmlDataSource x = new XmlDataSource();
    x.DataFile = URLString;
    x.XPath = String.Format(@"root/job [position() < 5]");

    xPathRepeater.DataSource = x;
    xPathRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the XML can be like below.

```
<Root>
   <Row id="1">
     <title>contact name 1</name>
     <desc>contact note 1</note>
   </Row>
   <Row id="2">
     <title>contact name 2</title>
     <desc>contact note 2</desc>
   </Row>
</Root>
```

Reference from **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f902wc3.aspx)**

Replace your HTML to following.

```
<h3><asp:Label ID="title" runat="server"></asp:Label></h3>
<p><asp:Label ID="desc" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
```

---

Register the `OnItemDataBound` Event of Repeater and write the following code..

```
protected void ED_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label title = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("title");
        title.Text = ((System.Xml.XmlElement)e.Item.DataItem).ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

        Label desc = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("desc");
        desc.Text = ((System.Xml.XmlElement)e.Item.DataItem).ChildNodes[1].InnerText.Substring(1, 300) + "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing, you may want to evaluate the `desc.text` to make sure your not cutting a word in half.

Comment: @Pankaj, I like where you're going with this. However, I'm not sure the code works. I got an error when trying to access the XML - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor' to type 'System.Xml.XmlElement'. The XML is the same as your example (less the row id). I'm not familiar enough with Xml to understand what's going wrong there.

Comment: can you post your sample XML and the code being used ur side ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the SubString on the value of the returned XPath query?

Comment: That seems like a good option. How would I apply that to the XML record? Moreover, the sub node? Thanks! And to be clear- I'm pulling this XML file and not creating it myself.